# VBA sort by oldest date

Tags: excel, vba

This problem is driving me crazy. Basically I need to sort a range from oldest date to newst date. When I implement this code to one sheet, it works, when I run on another sheet, it doesnt, despite the fact both sheets are basically the same (different numbers but same number of filled columns and rows)

I want that only the range totrng is sorted by the date, and not the entire sheet. While in sheet1 it works, in sheet2 it doesn't, and it sorts all the sheet based on the oldest date. Why is that?

```
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

Set totrng = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).CurrentRegion
totrng.Sort Key1:=Range("J4:J" & lr), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: yep I copied the code in all the sheets to first test it (and then I will substitute the activehseet with some object defined name like a "sheet"&i) The problem is that I dont understand why it sorts all the worksheet and not the totrng

Comment: error spotted. `Currentregion` is ok, the problem was that a cell had a space (ie it was not blank), so current region highlights all the region and not only the totrng.